# $q$-binomials in terms of ordinary binomials

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there a known identity that expresses the $q$-binomial coefficients (also known as Gaussian binomial coefficients) in terms of the (ordinary) binomial coefficients?

Comment: I'd guess no.  For the other direction, I'm sure you know that evaluation at $q=1$ gives the ordinary binomial coefficients.

Comment: No, there is not.